# Unable to load requested class CSSMin in the Production Server

Tags: php, codeigniter, carabiner

```
ubuntu@ip-10-0-0-116:/var/www$ grep -ri cssmin .
./projectapp/public_html/application/logs/log-2016-09-20.php:ERROR - 2016-09-20 06:19:15 --> Unable to load the requested class: Cssmin
./projectapp/public_html/application/logs/log-2016-09-20.php:ERROR - 2016-09-20 06:19:31 --> Unable to load the requested class: Cssmin
./projectapp/public_html/application/logs/log-2016-09-20.php:ERROR - 2016-09-20 06:19:34 --> Unable to load the requested class: Cssmin
./projectapp/public_html/application/logs/log-2016-09-20.php:ERROR - 2016-09-20 06:19:58 --> Unable to load the requested class: Cssmin
./projectapp/public_html/application/logs/log-2016-09-20.php:ERROR - 2016-09-20 06:20:13 --> Unable to load the requested class: Cssmin
./projectapp/public_html/application/libraries/Carabiner.php: * and CSSMin {@link http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/103269/ released here} libraries included.
./projectapp/public_html/application/libraries/Carabiner.php: $this->_load('cssmin');
./projectapp/public_html/application/libraries/Carabiner.php: $this->CI->cssmin->config(array('relativePath'=>$rel));
./projectapp/public_html/application/libraries/Carabiner.php: return $this->CI->cssmin->minify($contents);
./projectapp/public_html/application/libraries/CSSMin.php:$this->load->library('cssmin');
./projectapp/public_html/application/libraries/CSSMin.php:$this->cssmin->minify( file_get_contents('styles.css') );
./projectapp/public_html/application/libraries/CSSMin.php:$cssmin_options = array(
./projectapp/public_html/application/libraries/CSSMin.php:$this->cssmin->config($cssmin_options);
./projectapp/public_html/application/libraries/CSSMin.php:$this->cssmin->minify( $string, FALSE, $path );
./projectapp/public_html/application/libraries/CSSMin.php:class CSSMin
./projectapp/public_html/application/libraries/CSSMin.php:    public function CSSMin()
./projectapp/public_html/application/libraries/CSSMin.php:        log_message('debug', 'CSSMin library initialized.');
Binary file ./projectapp/index matches
./project1/public_html/application/libraries/carabiner.php: * and CSSMin {@link http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/103269/ released here} libraries included.
./project1/public_html/application/libraries/carabiner.php: $this->_load('cssmin');
./project1/public_html/application/libraries/carabiner.php: $this->CI->cssmin->config(array('relativePath'=>$rel));
./project1/public_html/application/libraries/carabiner.php: return $this->CI->cssmin->minify($contents);
./project1/public_html/application/libraries/cssmin.php: $this->load->library('cssmin');
./project1/public_html/application/libraries/cssmin.php: $this->cssmin->minify( file_get_contents('styles.css') );
./project1/public_html/application/libraries/cssmin.php: $cssmin_options = array(
./project1/public_html/application/libraries/cssmin.php: $this->cssmin->config($cssmin_options);
./project1/public_html/application/libraries/cssmin.php: $this->cssmin->minify( $string, FALSE, $path );
./project1/public_html/application/libraries/cssmin.php: class cssmin {
./project1/public_html/application/libraries/cssmin.php: public function cssmin()
./project1/public_html/application/libraries/cssmin.php: log_message('debug', 'CSSMin library initialized.');
```

I Know the class file is case sensitive on Loading and creating .
But I auto load carabiner library and called the css as
`$this->carabiner->css($css_assets);`
The all are working fine in the development server.But it is not working on Production server (Linux).As Per guessing, the Linux server checking the class is case sensitive .

How to solve CSSMin class to autoload with the Carabiner class file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You changed the file names? eg: cssmin.php changed to Cssmin.php ?

If so, you need to update the class names as well `class cssmin {` to `class Cssmin {`

Then try

Comment: Thanks, The issue is solved by changing the class name on production server.

Answer (score 0):

May I Know What the reason while getting these error "Unable to load requested class" .?

The Project is successfully running on development server(Linux) but not in production server(Linux).